# Python deployment with virtualenv (on a no-internet-access server)

Tags: python, deployment, virtualenv

My production server has no access to the internet, so it's a bit a mess copying all the dependencies from my dev machine to the production/development server.

If I'd use virtualenv, I'd have all my dependencies in this environment. Doing this I'd also be able to deploy it on any machine, which has python & virtualenv installed.

But I've seen this rarely, and it seems kind of dirty.
Am I wrong and this could be a good practice, or are there other ways to solve that nicely?

Comment: `virtualenv` does not allow you to deploy dependencies to other machines. you may consider `fabric` (http://fabfile.org) or a `bash` script to do that instead. `virtualenv` is great for isolate your development environments e.g. to fit your production environments.

Comment: You can try the bootstrap feature that virtualenv has to offer, see here for an example https://github.com/socialplanning/fassembler/blob/master/fassembler/create-venv-script.py

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three options I would consider:

1. Run your own [PyPI mirror](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0381/) with the dependencies you need. You really only need to build the file layout and pull from your local server using the `index-url` flag:

   `$ pip install --index-url http://pypi.beastcraft.net/ numpy`
2. Build virtualenvs on the same architecture and copy those over as needed.

   This works, but you're taking a risk on true portability.
3. Use [terrarium](https://github.com/PolicyStat/terrarium) to build virtual environments then bring those over (basically option 2 but with easier bookkeeping/automation).

I've done all of these and actually think that hosting your own PyPI mirror is the best option. It gives you the most flexibility when you're making a deployment or trying out new code.

Comment: There is a down side of hosting your own mirror compared to the other two options.  If you have conflicting/share dependencies you need to host on the same box you are going to need/want some kind of virtual environment.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv-clone/ might help (just found, not tried).