# virtualenv wont work once copied to a same arch machine - says "No module named copy"

Tags: python, virtualenv

related to the suggestion in [Python deployment with virtualenv (on a no-internet-access server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726146/python-deployment-with-virtualenv-on-a-no-internet-access-server)

I've built a virtualenv in one server, zipped it, and copied it to an internet-less prod server.

On the source machine everything works:

```
(test_scikit)[s-machine]$ uname -a
Linux truein03.fsc.local 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(test_scikit)[s-machine]$ cat /etc/*rel*
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
(test_scikit)[s-machine]$ which python
~/virtualenvs/test_scikit/bin/python
(test_scikit)[s-machine]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
(test_scikit)[s-machine]$  python -c "from copy import deepcopy"
```

But on the target machine it won't even find the built-in copy module!

```
(test_scikit)[t-machine]$ uname -a
Linux lvshdc2en0012 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14 11:36:39 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(test_scikit)[t-machine]$ cat /etc/*rel*
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
(test_scikit)[t-machine]$ which python
~/webcat_svm_poc/test_scikit/bin/python
(test_scikit)[t-machine]$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
(test_scikit)[t-machine]$ python -c "from copy import deepcopy"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named copy
```

Is it because of minor os distrib incompatibilities?

Comment: what happens if you do `ls -la ~/webcat_svm_poc/test_scikit/bin/python` ?

Comment: ls -la ~/webcat_svm_poc/test_scikit/bin/python
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ihadanny users 6206779 Nov 30 11:33 /x/home/ihadanny/webcat_svm_poc/test_scikit/bin/python