# how to copy my python virtualenv to another machine

Tags: virtualenv, move, packaging

I made my virtualenv on my ubuntu pc machine.
and I developed my project on there.

But I need to move my environment as it is include all packages.
because the target machine can't connect outside by network.
I have to move it by usb.

do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python deployment with virtualenv (on a no-internet-access server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726146/python-deployment-with-virtualenv-on-a-no-internet-access-server)

Answer (score 0):

I just copied `envs` directory .. and it works!
but I recommend to copy that base on platform compatibility